# Will caching my application data on the client using OutputCacheLocation.Client , expose the data to unauthorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have defined the following cache setting inside my asp.net mvc web application, to cache the action method data on the client:-

```
[Authorize]
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "VShort", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With")]
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = "", int page = 1)public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = "", int page = 1)
```

But I have the following question regarding the security concerns of caching data on the client:

1. If an authorized user access the system from a public PC, and the asp.net mvc web application uses windows authentication to authenticate users. So will external users who access the same public PC can see the cached data . or cached data can only be accessed and views by authenticated and authorized users ?
2. If caching data on the client will expose the data to external users, is there a way to make the client cached data more secure?
   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If accessing your application from shared desktop is expected than caching on client indeed can expose data.

In Windows "cache on client" is per-Windows-user. But in many cases "Windows user" and "website user" are 2 different concepts. Even if you use Windows authentication it is often possible to sign in to web site as different Windows user that currently logged on user.

Many sites also use non-Window authentication (using completely custom or third party identity systems like OAuth to Facebook/Google/Microsoft accounts) - in this case there is absolutely no ties between account browser runs under (cache scoped to this account) and "site account". You often see machines in "kiosk" mode on public machines shops/offices that let one place orders/check mail/Facebook and like without logging in/out from Windows.

If page contains some sort of data private specific for only particular user you are better of not caching it.

One possible approach to improve site performance in this case is to split pages into cacheable part with somewhat static content and non-cached user data loaded with AJAX.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so caching the data on the client side using OutputCacheLocation.Client might expose the data to external users , and in this case it is better to not use it , as in my case this data is considered private...